# React - using axios to update list and refresh at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a function `saveDocument` which does basically two things; sends a request to update my document and send another request to get the new data including the updated record. The problem is that `loadDocuments` is returning old data set, and not the updated. Seems that it is not waiting the update, even using async/await.

> saveDocument

```
async function saveDocument() {
    await updateDocument(selectedDocument);
    const response = await loadDocuments(selectedGroup.id);
    console.log(response);
    setDocuments(response);
}
```

> updateDocument

```
export const updateDocument = async (groupData) => {
  await api.put(`/documents/${groupData.id}`, groupData);
};
```

> loadDocuments

```
export const loadDocuments = async (groupId) => {
  const { data } = await api.get('/documents', { params: { groupId } });
  return data;
};
```

If i wrap the function `loadDocuments` with a setTimeout it works perfectly, cause there is time to update and then get the most recent results. But it should work with async/await as well. What am i doing wrong? Example:

```
async function saveDocument() {
    await updateDocument(selectedDocument);

    setTimeout(async () => {
      const response = await loadDocuments(selectedGroup.id);
      console.log(response);
      setDocuments(response);
    }, 2000)
  }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you post the whole code?

Comment: Yes, look fine. Maybe you don't have await logic on backend? For example, backend instantly answers for update request, but only start actual update after that and your frontend is already requesting updated data which is not updated yet.

Comment: Thank you guys, i found out that was exactly this problem, missing await on my backend hahahha